# How is it possible to revise for a maths test of this type - Which is the best method to solve it

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, finance

I need some help with this question, My answer to question E) is 1880 pounds per year, can anyone suggest a different answer, also does anyone know how would I revise for questions of this type.

> Give answers, where appropriate, to 1 decimal place.
>
> Julia Parsons runs a small business hiring out canoes and pedaloes
>   (pedal boats) in a seaside holiday resort during the summer months.
>   The canoes and pedaloes are subjected to considerable “wear and tear”.
>
> Julia’s “fleet” consists of
>
> - 10 single canoes (canoes for a single person)
> - 12 double canoes (canoes for 2 persons)
> - 12 pedaloes (pedal boats)
> - 2 large canoes (canoes for 4 persons)
>
> The hiring costs per hour for these are,
>   Single £4;
>   Double £6;
>   Pedaloes £3;
>   Large £8
>
> Julia has kept a record of usage over several years and assesses the
>   total usage according to the following table.
>
> Table 1 Number of occasions when canoe/pedalo is hired for the period
>   shown
>
> Due to the heavy “wear and tear” each pedalo has to be replaced every
>   3 years and each canoe every 5 years. Julia maintains a depreciation
>   fund for this purpose and puts the same amount of money each year in
>   to this fund. The costs for new are,
>   Single £200;
>   Double £230;
>   Pedaloes £150;
>   Large £400
>
> (e) How much does Julia put in to the fund each year?

Comment: By my calculations the replacement cost averages £1712 a year: in a 15-year span she must replace 30 single canoes, 36 double canoes, 60 pedaloes, and 6 large canoes, at a total cost of £25680. Putting in £1712 a year is therefore a steady-state solution. However, it’s not enough starting from scratch, because at the end of 6 years she’s had to pay £12920 and has deposited only £10272.

Comment: Ignore that last sentence: the £12920 figure is wrong.

Comment: Table 1 is missing. . .

How can we answer this if we don't know "number of occasions when canoe/pedalo is hired for the period shown"? That affects the answer entirely.

Answer (score 1):

If a single canoe lasts 5 years and costs 200, you need to add 200/5=40 to the depreciation fund for each boat, or 400/year for the fleet of 10.  The others are similar:  230*12/5=552 for double canoes, 150*12/3=600 for pedaloes, 2*400/5=160 for large canoes (assuming they last 5 years), giving me 1712.  If the large canoes last only 3 years, they need 266.7 per year, giving 1818.7

Answer (score 0):

You can work out the annual replacement costs, as Ross did in his answer, or you can first work out the total replacement cost over a convenient period, as I did in my comment. Since $15$ is the least common multiple of $3$ and $5$, $15$ years is a convenient period: each pedalo must be replaced $5$ times, and each canoe $3$ times. Thus, the total replacement cost in pounds is

$$5\cdot 150\cdot 12+3\Big(200\cdot 10+230\cdot 12+400\cdot 2\Big)=25680$$

over $15$ years, or $\dfrac{25680}{15}=1712$ pounds a year.

This answer assumes that the depreciation fund does not earn interest, since nothing is said about interest in the problem. And contrary to what I said in my comment, the fund is always sufficient to cover the replacement costs. Assuming that the replacement fund starts at $0$, here’s a table of the total replacement costs and the amount in the fund at the points at which craft are replaced:

$$\begin{array}{r|r|r}
\text{Year}&\text{Total Costs}&\text{Paid to Fund}\\ \hline
0&0&0\\
3&1800&5136\\
5&7360&8560\\
6&9160&10272\\
9&10960&15408\\
10&16520&17120\\
12&18320&20540\\
15&25680&25680
\end{array}$$